# Python MySQLdb custom function error

Tags: python, mysql-python

I have a custom function defined like so:

```
def create_extract_position_type_1(self):

    self.c.execute("""CREATE FUNCTION extract_position_type_1 (f_str VARCHAR)

                        RETURNS VARCHAR

                        BEGIN

                        DECLARE pstr VARCHAR(1600)

                        SET pstr = SUBSTRING(f_str, "|", 4)

                        RETURN pstr

                        END""")
```

When I run this function I get this error:

```
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\tRETURNS VARCHAR\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t    BEGIN\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t    DECLARE pstr VARCHAR(1600)' at line 1")
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syntax of SQL needs some correction.
VARCHAR should have length limit

Try this

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION extract_position_type_1(f_str VARCHAR(500) ) RETURNS VARCHAR(500)
BEGIN
    DECLARE pstr VARCHAR(1600);
    SET pstr = SUBSTRING(f_str, '|', 4);
    RETURN pstr;
END
```